Where's my error in the calculation of the CDF of the product of two random variables?

I have an event that I'd like to model as the product of a random variable $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$.
I'd like to see the quantiles of my theoretical model, for which I'll need the inverse CDF. Let's focus on just the CDF because once I have that I will get the quantiles numerically. If I'm not mistaken, I should be able to "integrate out" one of the variables to get the CDF of the product:
$${\rm P}(XY \le z) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty {\rm P}(i\cdot Y\le z){\rm P}(X=i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty {\rm P}(Y\le \frac{z}{i}){\rm P}(X=i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty F_Y(\frac{z}{i})f_X(i)$$
Where $F_Y$ and $f_X$ are the CDF and PDF of $Y$ and $X$, respectively.
I have observed data that has lead to the following specific estimates:
$$\array{\alpha = 0.6668210 \\
         \beta = 0.0005504091 \\
         \lambda =0.8
        }$$
And yet the theoretical result differs enormously from any large simulations I run. For instance this simulation in R gives:
alpha<-0.6668210
beta<-0.0005504091
lambda<-0.8

summary(rgamma(100000,shape = alpha,rate = beta)*rpois(100000,lambda))

    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
    0.00     0.00    60.12   983.18  1073.34 63352.16

And yet, if I do the theoretical calculation on the median I get:
> sum(pgamma(60/1:100,shape = alpha,rate = beta)*dpois(1:100,lambda))
[1] 0.05317277

I'm only summing to 100 because above that it gets insignificant (actually it becomes insignificant at like, 4)
I feel like I have to be missing something really silly here like a flipped fraction or a sign or index or something but I have been at this task for so long that my brain is foggy. Or maybe it's something conceptually wrong with the whole thing. Any ideas?

One possible source of your problem: In the sum you are omitting the $i=0$ term, and because $XY=0$ precisely when $X=0$ (a.s.) and $P[X=0]=e^{-0.8} = 0.449...$, the omission is significant.

@JohnDawkins You're totally right. I quickly reasoned away that term as 0 due to the gamma factor, but I realize now it's actually $1$. ‍♂️

@GPerez I brought up the new ta on meta: Should there be a separate tag for the programming language R? What should the tag be called?
